# SQL determine column name next to a particular column

Tags: sql, python-3.x

**Here is the scenario...**

I have an SQL table with columns:

```
Power | Quality1 | Energy | Quality2 | Voltage | Quality3... Current | Quality165 | Temp | Quality166
```

I want to extract the data contained in for example the column labelled as '**Quality3**', which tells me what the quality of the data is regarding the voltage data, with column '**Voltage**' containing the actual value. However, I have hundreds of columns and I am not always sure which '**Quality#**' table to select in order to obtain the quality of the recorded data for a particular table entry.

So to be clear, I don't know that '**Quality166**' informs me of the '**Temp**' column's data validity, but I do know that the column proceeding the '**Temp**' column contains the quality information that I desire.

I have thought of maybe getting the column number where for example the column is labelled as '**Voltage**'. Now, as mentioned, I don't know that column '**Quality3**' is associated with the 'Voltage' column's entry, but if I could perhaps obtain the actual number of the 'Voltage' column entry (**5** in this case) then if i wanted to get the '**Quality3**' value I could simply search for it in column 6, which contains this desired data.

Any suggestions ?

This is what I've tried, but I am way off...

```
query = "SELECT count() FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'Plant_Data_raw' AND table_name = 'Voltage'"
```

Looking forward to your replies !

Comment: Refactor that table. If you don't know what column has your data and you are guessing based on proximity to another column, that is not great.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are getting at here but sounds like something you could solve with dynamic sql - looping through rows and concatenating the rowid into each new field as you go

Comment: Wait, so the columns relate to the column *next to it*? Or another table? What's stored in the `Power` column itself if `Quality1` holds the power data? I am really curious now.

Comment: What's the DBMS you're using?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for answers, but believe me, my question is very specific and there is no other way. So basically, I am looking for the index of a column and then I just want to find the value in the column next to it...

Comment: Jacob H - Ok, so the table is the same. I only want to obtain values in columns within the table. I have hundreds of columns in this table. The power column contains a Power-value like for example 25054 (kilowatts). But this measurement could be faulty and the value of 25054 could be completely wrong...thus, the Quality column (located left of the power column) informs me if the data reading was 'good' or 'bad'. and whether or not it can be trusted.

Comment: So, to re-iterate my question...I simply want to execute a SCL query that gets the Power column's value (for a particular time stamp), as well as the Quality column's value (located to the left of the power column). This will help me to verify in my data analysis whether or not readings can be trusted from which ever column (energy, current, voltage...) I am extracting them from.

Comment: Sticky bit - I am using MariaDB which is a well known community-developed fork of the MySQL relational database management system